# Timestampdiff issue while attempting to execute, errors don't make sense

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm attempting to use the time difference between two timestamps with where. I realize that there are various posts on how to do this and I've looked at them.

Code:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
WHERE TIMESTAMP_DIFF('SECOND', started_at, ended_at) <= 60 
  AND started_at IS NOT NULL
  AND ended_at IS NOT NULL;
```

However, BigQuery keeps throwing an error.

> A valid date part name is required but found ended_at at [3:107]

So I look at the schema.

```
started_at  TIMESTAMP   NULLABLE        
ended_at    TIMESTAMP   NULLABLE
```

While it's certainly possible, I'm doing something wrong. The error would lead me to believe that this is an issue with the column itself.  I've also tried it with clauses for `where ended_at is not null and started_at is not null`. While the query for everything returns if I search that way, as soon as I put timestamp into it, it doesn't work.

NOTE: I realize that the `timestampdiff()` function doesn't have an underscore typically, but BigQuery uses that syntax according to the note if you type it the other way.

> Function not found: TIMESTAMPDIFF; Did you mean timestamp_diff? at [3:71]

Comment: see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#timestamp_diff

Comment: use **TIMESTAMP_DIFF(ended_at, started_at, SECOND) <= 60**  instead.

Answer (score 1):

`TIMESTAMP_DIFF(ended_at, started_at, SECOND)` should do the trick

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#timestamp_diff

Example:

[image]

Comment: appreciate it, all the reference sites I looked at said timestampdiff(unit, timea, timeb) Appreciate it. Fairly new to bigquery.